# QueryOver HAVING clause with AND condition

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to create a HAVING clause with and AND in it and it creates a WHERE clause of it.

I tested it out and it seems like the problem only occurs when I have an AND or an OR.

Here you can see a simplified version of the code (both parts of the AND restriction is the same, just to simplify the problem).

```
eventQuery = eventQuery.Where(
                    Restrictions.And(
                        Restrictions.Le(
                            Projections.Conditional(
                                Restrictions.LeProperty( Projections.Property( () => aEvent.StartDate.End ), Projections.Max( () => aMeeting.Duration.Start ) ),
                                Projections.Max( () => aMeeting.Duration.Start ),
                                Projections.Property( () => aEvent.StartDate.End ) ),

                            DateTime.Now ),

                    Restrictions.Le(
                        Projections.Conditional(
                            Restrictions.LeProperty( Projections.Property( () => aEvent.StartDate.End ), Projections.Max( () => aMeeting.Duration.Start ) ),
                            Projections.Max( () => aMeeting.Duration.Start ),
                            Projections.Property( () => aEvent.StartDate.End ) ),

                        DateTime.Now ) )

                    );
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to achieve. I see no `Having` in your example. Could you describe what you want as an SQL query?

Comment: I'd like this whole criteria to create a having clause instead of where. As you can see my criteria contains an aggregated value (max) so this condition has to be in a having clause. The generated query doesn't run only because of this issue.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the query?

Comment: @GáborBakos: Unfortunately, `.Where` is used to create a `HAVING` clause

Comment: I'm not at my work pc until tomorrow unfortunately but the other parts seem irrelevant. The problem doesnt occur until I write an And or OR condition e.g keeping only one side of this AND condition (a Restricions.Le) works perfectly and creates the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem doesn't seem to have a solution so we decided to create a View of this query instead so we can map it to a model and write the QueryOver with a Where clause against the selected-calculated fields.